# Spring Data Neo4j - Cross store persistence

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-graph

I am new to SDN, I am trying to do a cross store persistence with hibernate. The [tutorial](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-graph/snapshot-site/reference/html/#d5e1163) given in website has examples for the same, I have checked the github ones too. I have two questions

1. I am unable to do xml configuration as mentioned in the docs or examples. `<neo4j:config/>` doesn't support `entityManagerFactory`. My assumption is it creates the default [Neo4jConfiguration](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/2.0.0.RC1/api/org/springframework/data/neo4j/config/Neo4jConfiguration.html) which doesn't have a setter for `entityManagerFactory`. The workaround i have found is to define a [CrossStoreNeo4jConfiguration](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/2.0.0.RC1/api/org/springframework/data/neo4j/cross_store/config/CrossStoreNeo4jConfiguration.html) bean.

   ```
   @Bean
   public CrossStoreNeo4jConfiguration crossStoreNeo4jConfiguration(){
   CrossStoreNeo4jConfiguration configuration = new CrossStoreNeo4jConfiguration();
   configuration.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
   configuration.setGraphDatabaseService(graphDatabaseService);
   return configuration;
   }
   ```

   How to do this inside`<neo4j:config/>`
2. What happens when you refer a Neo4jTemplate to your repository using `neo4j-template-ref` when you define repositories using `neo4j:repositories`? what is the purpose?

**UDPATE**

The reason it was unable to create `CrossStoreNeo4jConfiguration` with `<neo4j:config/> was` , i was missing the dependency spring-data-neo4j-cross-store`. But now i get exception on application start up.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Singleton 'nodeEntityStateFactory' isn't currently in creation
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.afterSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:312)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:239)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:292)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.cross_store.config.CrossStoreNeo4jConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$779c5955.nodeEntityStateFactory(<generated>)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.mappingContext(Neo4jConfiguration.java:199)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.cross_store.config.CrossStoreNeo4jConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$779c5955.CGLIB$mappingContext$11(<generated>)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.cross_store.config.CrossStoreNeo4jConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$779c5955$$FastClassByCGLIB$$3134c8a8.invoke(<generated>)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:280)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.cross_store.config.CrossStoreNeo4jConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$779c5955.mappingContext(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:149)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<neo4j:config entityManagerFactory="entityManagerFactory"/>
```

No need to create your custom implementation.

The template passed to the repository config is the one used by its infrastructure. In most cases there is no need to configure something different.

Comment: I get this exception when using that java.lang.IllegalStateException: Singleton 'nodeEntityStateFactory' isn't currently in creation. I have update my question with full stack trace.

Comment: which spring version are you using? Could you update to 3.1.0.RELEASE?

Comment: Looks like [this](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8824?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel) is the issue. The intercept method gets invoked umpteen times but the bean never gets created, and finally throws the exception. But how can it happen in 3.1.1? I tried working with 3.1.2, but still facing the issue.

Comment: If i remove the transaction part in my app, the error goes off (the bean is created).

Comment: I have asked a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12353353/spring-data-neo4j-using-transactions-causes-infinite-loop) on this.