# Spring Data Neo4j- using transactions causes infinite loop

Tags: spring, transactions, neo4j, spring-transactions, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to integrate SDN with my spring-hibernate app. With minimal `<neo4j:config>` and `<neo4j:repositories>` configuration, it works fine. But when i include either `@Neo4jTransactional` or write a custom `transactionManager` i get an infinite loop in creating `nodeEntityStateFactory` bean in the intercept method in `ConfigurationClassEnhancer` class. Here is the exception i get.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Singleton 'nodeEntityStateFactory' isn't currently in creation
```

Here is the intercept method.

```
        public Object intercept(Object enhancedConfigInstance, Method beanMethod, Object[] beanMethodArgs,
                MethodProxy cglibMethodProxy) throws Throwable {

        String beanName = BeanAnnotationHelper.determineBeanNameFor(beanMethod);


        Scope scope = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(beanMethod, Scope.class);
        if (scope != null && scope.proxyMode() != ScopedProxyMode.NO) {
            String scopedBeanName = ScopedProxyCreator.getTargetBeanName(beanName);
            if (this.beanFactory.isCurrentlyInCreation(scopedBeanName)) {
                beanName = scopedBeanName;
            }
        }


        if (factoryContainsBean('&'+beanName) && factoryContainsBean(beanName)) {
            Object factoryBean = this.beanFactory.getBean('&'+beanName);
            if (factoryBean instanceof ScopedProxyFactoryBean) {

            }
            else {

                return enhanceFactoryBean(factoryBean.getClass(), beanName);
            }
        }

        boolean factoryIsCaller = beanMethod.equals(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.getCurrentlyInvokedFactoryMethod());
        boolean factoryAlreadyContainsSingleton = this.beanFactory.containsSingleton(beanName);
        if (factoryIsCaller && !factoryAlreadyContainsSingleton) {

            if (BeanFactoryPostProcessor.class.isAssignableFrom(beanMethod.getReturnType())) {
                logger.warn(String.format("@Bean method %s.%s is non-static and returns an object " +
                        "assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will " +
                        "result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, " +
                        "@Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring " +
                        "@Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid " +
                        "these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean Javadoc for complete details",
                        beanMethod.getDeclaringClass().getSimpleName(), beanMethod.getName()));
            }
               //This doesn't invoke the @bean annotated constructor which it should. Instead it comes back to the method.
            return cglibMethodProxy.invokeSuper(enhancedConfigInstance, beanMethodArgs); 
        }
        else {

            boolean alreadyInCreation = this.beanFactory.isCurrentlyInCreation(beanName);
            try {
                if (alreadyInCreation) {
                    this.beanFactory.setCurrentlyInCreation(beanName, false);
                }
                return this.beanFactory.getBean(beanName);
            } finally {
                if (alreadyInCreation) {
                    this.beanFactory.setCurrentlyInCreation(beanName, true);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

say, i am using TM for two methods.

```
I have two methods

@Transactional
methodA(){} // access using entityManager (hibernate)

@Neo4jTransactional
methodB(){} // access using entityRepository interface (SDN)
```

Even if i try using the ChainedTransactionManager and annotate methodB with @Transactional, the same error occurs.
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Full stacktrace

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.TypeRepresentationStrategyFactory org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.typeRepresentationStrategyFactory() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'indexProvider' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/neo4j/cross_store/config/CrossStoreNeo4jConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.index.IndexProvider org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.indexProvider() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingContext' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/neo4j/cross_store/config/CrossStoreNeo4jConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.mappingContext() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Singleton 'nodeEntityStateFactory' isn't currently in creation
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:169)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:570)
... 183 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'indexProvider' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/neo4j/cross_store/config/CrossStoreNeo4jConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.index.IndexProvider org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.indexProvider() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingContext' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/neo4j/cross_store/config/CrossStoreNeo4jConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.mappingContext() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Singleton 'nodeEntityStateFactory' isn't currently in creation
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:581)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1015)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:911)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:292)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.cross_store.config.CrossStoreNeo4jConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$908ddc4b.indexProvider(<generated>)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.typeRepresentationStrategyFactory(Neo4jConfiguration.java:144)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.cross_store.config.CrossStoreNeo4jConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$908ddc4b.CGLIB$typeRepresentationStrategyFactory$18(<generated>)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.cross_store.config.CrossStoreNeo4jConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$908ddc4b$$FastClassByCGLIB$$8d1abdaa.invoke(<generated>)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:280)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.cross_store.config.CrossStoreNeo4jConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$908ddc4b.typeRepresentationStrategyFactory(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:149)
... 184 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.index.IndexProvider org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.indexProvider() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingContext' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/neo4j/cross_store/config/CrossStoreNeo4jConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.mappingContext() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Singleton 'nodeEntityStateFactory' isn't currently in creation
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:169)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:570)
... 205 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingContext' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/neo4j/cross_store/config/CrossStoreNeo4jConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.mappingContext() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Singleton 'nodeEntityStateFactory' isn't currently in creation
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:581)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1015)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:911)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:292)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.cross_store.config.CrossStoreNeo4jConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$908ddc4b.mappingContext(<generated>)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.indexProvider(Neo4jConfiguration.java:266)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.cross_store.config.CrossStoreNeo4jConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$908ddc4b.CGLIB$indexProvider$32(<generated>)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.cross_store.config.CrossStoreNeo4jConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$908ddc4b$$FastClassByCGLIB$$8d1abdaa.invoke(<generated>)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:280)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.cross_store.config.CrossStoreNeo4jConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$908ddc4b.indexProvider(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:149)
... 206 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.mappingContext() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Singleton 'nodeEntityStateFactory' isn't currently in creation
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:169)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:570)
... 227 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Singleton 'nodeEntityStateFactory' isn't currently in creation
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.afterSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:312)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:239)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:292)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.cross_store.config.CrossStoreNeo4jConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$908ddc4b.nodeEntityStateFactory(<generated>)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.mappingContext(Neo4jConfiguration.java:199)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.cross_store.config.CrossStoreNeo4jConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$908ddc4b.CGLIB$mappingContext$11(<generated>)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.cross_store.config.CrossStoreNeo4jConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$908ddc4b$$FastClassByCGLIB$$8d1abdaa.invoke(<generated>)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:280)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.cross_store.config.CrossStoreNeo4jConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$908ddc4b.mappingContext(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:149)
... 228 more
```

Comment: what spring and sdn versions do you use? I think there was something related to this fixed in Spring 3.1, also could you share the full stacktrace?

Comment: I am using 3.1.2 (i found that the issue is fixed in 3.1) and SDN 2.0.1. The stack trace is too long, with too many BeanCreationException s. I will paste as much as possible.

Comment: I have created a small project on github replicating the issue. Here is the link : https://github.com/shazinahmed/SDN-Transaction

Comment: Shazin, see http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?130011-Spring-Data-Neo4j-java-lang-IllegalStateException&p=424459#post424459

Comment: Hey Lasse, if you can update this as answer, i would be glad to accept it with an upvote :D